# Best way to programatically run BigQuery Queries and upload into a table

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I have to cross join 2 rather massive data sets that currently fails.  I want to split up data sets into logical chunks.  I plan to use Python to run the queries in order with a variable that changes during each run of the loop e.g:

```
while x <= 100:
  #Code to query in BigQuery: [SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2 WHERE table1.field = 'x'] then write the query results to a JSON file or upload directly in BigQuery
  x += 1 #X is a counter
```

It looks like the response from a singular bigquery query is a JSON file but I'm stuck on figuring out how to upload and append this to a table. When I try to upload the JSON file manually in BigQuery it errors out - I'm not entirely sure how to format it such that BigQuery reads it correctly.

Questions: 
  1. Is this a good way to do it?
  2. How do I prep the JSON file such that it uploads successfully in BigQuery?
  3. What's the best way to do this automatically?  (Presumably through the API)

Answer (score 1):

Info about ingesting data in BigQuery can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery

However, I'm not sure how your scenario and your question are connected. Why do you need to upload data in JSON in order to run this query (assuming table1 and table2 are already in BQ)?

Also, why do you need to perform a cross join? Cross joins can be extremely expensive, because if you cross join two massive tables, your output will be unmanageably huge. The main use for cross joins in BQ is to simulate more complex join conditions (e.g., `<=`) by cross joining and then immediately filtering the output. Even that is expensive, though, so I'd encourage you to think about other ways to compute the answer you want.

Comment: Definitely understood re:cross joins.  Most of my peers and I can't really figure out another way though.  We have 2 tables with Geospatial points over time (x,y,timestamp) and we need to know when 2 points are near each other.  We used a divide and conquer approach to break it out but there are enough pieces that I would need to do it this way.

Comment: To answer your questions about JSON, I just want a way I can upload manually from python to test a few things - not required.  What's the best way to run a query many times over in BQ with a changing variable and dump all the results into one table?

Comment: What's your definition of "near"? If it's within a bounded distance, then perhaps you can assign points to buckets by location and then join on those buckets. Anything you can do to reduce the size of that cross join will be tremendously helpful (not to mention cheaper!).

Comment: If this is just for manual testing, I'd suggest using the "bq" command line tool or the web UI. If you want to write code from Python, try bigquery_client.py for a slightly nicer interface. To check out all the options for where to write data and how to append vs. overwrite, see the query options here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query

Comment: And if you *really* want the gory details, here's the definitive source for info: http://www.amazon.com/Google-BigQuery-Analytics-Jordan-Tigani/dp/1118824822

Comment: Yes - bucketing is exactly what I meant by dividing and conquering :).  I ran singular tests and have approached a small enough size that I'm comfortable with.  It can't be too small otherwise I'll miss too many that are over a border.  Now I just need to run that query for each possible iteration of a bucket!

I think Jobs is what I was looking for - I'm rather new to Python so any example on how to call a job that would write/append to a table would really help as I'm a little slow trying to dissect the Jobs page.

Comment: Note that you could potentially do all of this in SQL, without running lots of queries. You could run a first query that assigns a bucket to each data point, stored as a separate column of your table. Then run another query that joins on the bucket column and filters the joined results according to your actual distance metric. (You can even combine those into a single giant query.) No Python needed, and because you're running fewer scans of the data, your bill will be lower.

Comment: If you do want help writing Python, though, I'd recommend looking at the source code for the "bq" command line tool, which will show you how to issue a simple load job or query job. (Note that another alternative is to just to write a script that invokes "bq" directly, which might be easier in some scenarios.)